# How to add prefix to each element of XML

Tags: php, xml

how can I add prefix to each element of my XML.

So in general from XML like this:

```
<CLASSXml>
    <CalculationIndex>
        <RunDesc>NormalCalc</RunDesc>
    </CalculationIndex>
    <GlobalData>
        <CalcIdent>
            <CalcUId>CLASS:20160105:09411486:000007773000:203:CS:CZK:349074</CalcUId>
            <CalcNo>2454307119</CalcNo>
            <CustomNo>349074</CustomNo>
            <CalcVer>2300</CalcVer>
            <XMLVer>23.00.01</XMLVer>
            <Detail>
                <Current>1123</Current>
                <Last>1152</Last>
            </Detail>
            <ClassBuild>23.00.04.03</ClassBuild>
            <SAXIFVersion>6.2</SAXIFVersion>
            <SystemDat>2016-01-05</SystemDat>
            <TimeStamp>09:41:14.86</TimeStamp>
            <ProdMasterVer>0</ProdMasterVer>
        </CalcIdent>
    </GlobalData>
</CLASSXml>
```

Make something like this:

```
<ns2:CLASSXml>
    <ns2:CalculationIndex>
        <ns2:RunDesc>NormalCalc</ns2:RunDesc>
    </ns2:CalculationIndex>
    <ns2:GlobalData>
        <ns2:CalcIdent>
            <ns2:CalcUId>CLASS:20160105:09411486:000007773000:203:CS:CZK:349074</ns2:CalcUId>
            <ns2:CalcNo>2454307119</ns2:CalcNo>
            <ns2:CustomNo>349074</ns2:CustomNo>
            <ns2:CalcVer>2300</ns2:CalcVer>
            <ns2:XMLVer>23.00.01</ns2:XMLVer>
            <ns2:Detail>
                <ns2:Current>1123</ns2:Current>
                <ns2:Last>1152</ns2:Last>
            </ns2:detail>
            <ns2:ClassBuild>23.00.04.03</ns2:ClassBuild>
            <ns2:SAXIFVersion>6.2</ns2:SAXIFVersion>
            <ns2:SystemDat>2016-01-05</ns2:SystemDat>
            <ns2:TimeStamp>09:41:14.86</ns2:TimeStamp>
            <ns2:ProdMasterVer>0</ns2:ProdMasterVer>
        </ns2:CalcIdent>
    </ns2:GlobalData>
</ns2:CLASSXml>
```

I understand there is possible to do something like this with str_replace (as example below) but it is just heavy messy code which is useless if XML become 500 lines long or something similar.

Any ideas how can I do this simple?

```
public function addNameSpace($xml) {
    $xml = str_replace('<CLASSXml>', '<ns2:CLASSXml>', $xml);
    $xml = str_replace('</CLASSXml>', '</ns2:CLASSXml>', $xml);
    $xml = str_replace('<CalculationIndex>', '<ns2:CalculationIndex>', $xml);
    $xml = str_replace('</CalculationIndex>', '</ns2:CalculationIndex>', $xml);

    // What to do?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regex in PHP, It will be very easy

```
$xmlString = preg_replace( '/(?<=\<)([^\/].*?)(?=\>)/', 'ns2:$1', $xmlString); // for <test>
$xmlString = preg_replace( '/(?<=\<\/)(.*?)(?=\>)/', 'ns2:$1', $xmlString); // for </test>
```

Where $xmlString is your xml content.

Your function

```
public function addNameSpace($xml)
{
    $xml = preg_replace( '/(?<=\<)([^\/].*?)(?=\>)/', 'ns2:$1', $xml );
    $xml = preg_replace( '/(?<=\<\/)(.*?)(?=\>)/', 'ns2:$1', $xml ); 
    .
    .
}
```

or suggested: for different namespace

```
public function addNameSpace($xml, $namespace)
{
    $xml = preg_replace( '/(?<=\<)([^\/].*?)(?=\>)/', $namespace.'$1', $xml );
    $xml = preg_replace( '/(?<=\<\/)(.*?)(?=\>)/', $namespace.'$1', $xml ); 
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Hi @Vegeta, thank you for answer, regex could be really helpfull.
But if I can I have question for 2 things
1th - code above return <ns2:RunDesc>NormalCalc<ns2:/RunDesc> so slash is after prefix instead of before in ending tag
2th - I belieave this will not work for element with attribute like <element value="4"> </element> am I right?

Comment: Hi @Vegeta, really dont need to be sorry for "wrong" answer, even with first one you lead me nice way. I wasn't answering  because I was checking this. I found small mystake and maybe this lead to problem. Can we cointinue discus in chat and then you just come back and edit answer here?
Is it okey for you?
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100042/how-to-add-prefix-to-each-element-of-xml

Answer (score -1):

Right now on which technology you are using .. 
there is a method in spring in which you can add prefix to each element ..

```
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", new NamespacePrefixMapper() {
             @Override
            public String getPreferredPrefix(String arg0, String arg1, boolean arg2) {
                return "ns1";
            }
        });'
```

Or there is another way to do this

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://www.example.com/a",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
    xmlns = {
        @XmlNs(prefix="ns1", namespaceURI="http://www.example.com/a")
    }
)  

package authenticator.beans.login;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

Comment: Hi Kunal Gantra, I appriciate your answer however I have this in PHP not JAVA :( so SPRINT is not helpfull for me.
Anyway thanks again